# What is the best way to create a new blank UI while keeping the ABP Framework infrastructure?

Tags: multi-tenant, abp

In a Multitenancy B2C application, the interface created by the **Application Startup Template** applies well to the backoffice, but for the storefront website I think it would be necessary to create a blank UI project (angular or MVC).

What would be the best practice for keep the ABP infrastructure that provides functionality such as customization by Tenant, Tag Hellpers, Proxies, Localization, etc. without bringing unnecessary dependencies such as JS libraries and other components like menus, datatables, sidebars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a **Public** application template. Abp framework is created modularity in mind so that you can use modules in each other if they are developed in [modular way](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Best-Practices/Module-Architecture#layers-packages).

I don't think it is feasable to say "*add these projects and libraries*".

However, you can check the microservice demo, **PublicWebSite** application at [abp-samples](https://github.com/abpframework/abp-samples/tree/master/MicroserviceDemo/applications/PublicWebSite.Host) to see which libraries are added so that you can modify an empty project as you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding a View Component The ABP Framework, pre-built themes and modules define some re-usable view components. These view components can be replaced just like a page described above.

https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/AspNetCore/Customization-User-Interface#overriding-a-view-component

Replacing ALL UI Theme Package with your custom Project by copy the Basic Theme (from Github).

MVC https://community.abp.io/articles/creating-a-new-ui-theme-by-copying-the-basic-theme-for-mvc-ui-yt9b18io

Blazor https://community.abp.io/articles/creating-a-new-ui-theme-by-copying-the-basic-theme-for-blazor-ui-qaf5ho1b

Or check these others links https://community.abp.io/articles/changing-ui-theme-for-abp-mvc-razor-pages-ui-ravx6a0o.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30411757)